# print list metric with list_metrics() from cloud logging api (generator Expression 0x3e9bfe2fb4c0>)

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging, generator-expression

I want to log all the log-based metrics I have in my gcp project with a cloud function in python. I'm trying to run the following code sample:

```
for metric in client.list_metrics():  # API call(s)
    #do_something_with(metric)
    print(metric)
```

I have the following log output:

`"<google.cloud.logging_v2.metric.Metric object at 0x3e9bfe2fb4c0>"`

How do I read this? I tried `list()`, `json.loads()`, `json.dumps()` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I just noticed this part of your question --> "I get down voted on this question and I don't understand why.". I'm not one of the downvoters so I'm not sure on their reasoning but I think it's because your question is about the fundamentals of Python in general. What objects are and how you should handle them is explained in every basic course. Combined with the fact that it can be easily googled I think it might be the reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting back a python object:

> "<google.cloud.logging_v2.metric.Metric **object** at 0x3e9bfe2fb4c0>"

According to [this documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/1.15.0/metric.html) it has some properties.

So something like

```
print(metric.name)
```

should work for you.

Comment: Is there a way to explore an object like this without having access to the documentation? Or do you need to have access to the doc? How can I know the key to get the global object for example? If I want to print the entire list directly?

Comment: Sorry adding another comment; `metric.name` is working but not `metric.filter`...

Comment: You can always use print(dir(metric)) but that will not always be fully explained. Most of the time I would just trust documentation though, especially with suppliers the size of google.

Comment: As a sidenote: It's imho always better in these kind of scenario's to debug and step through code where possible. Dir will get you far but does not for example make distinction between properties and methods, which you have to figure out for yourself.